# How to bulk change one column? I want all values times 1.5

Tags: mysql, django

Currently I have a table called players_db .. I have about 20 columns in this table but one of them I want to bulk change instead of one by one. The name of this column is: PS_Lbin  -- So I want to multiply all values (numbers) that are in column PS_Lbin times 1.5

hopefully someone can help me out, thanks

Also, tell me how to reverse, such as divide it back to 1.5

For example, in this case it looks like this

```
id  | name  | PS_Lbin 
------------------------
1   | One   | 100
2   | Two   | 21312
3   | Three | 4871223
4   | Four  | 213
5   | Five  | 44411
```

Answer (score 5):

Use django `F()` expression and `update()`:

```
from django.db.models import F
Model.objects.filter(condition=condition).update(field=F('field') * 1.5))
```

django doc about [F()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/expressions/#f-expressions) and [update](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#update).

PS: Your model names are not following python class conventions. The should be capfirst with no underscores in between. Check [pep8 doc](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#class-names) for python class naming details.

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE players_db SET PS_Lbin = PS_Lbin * 1.5;
```

To divide, replace the * with a /.

Note that if you have an integer column, your multiplication and division by a float will lead to data loss.

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL you will have to use the `Update` command

```
UPDATE players_db SET PS_Lbin = PS_Lbin * 1.5;
```

In order to divide, you would just replace the multiiply (*) with divide (/)

```
UPDATE players_db SET PS_Lbin = PS_Lbin / 1.5;
```

However, just according how your database is setup you may need to  use a where statement. Just add a fake comparison to initiate it.

```
UPDATE players_db SET PS_Lbin = PS_Lbin * 1.5 where 10 = 10;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this in a Python shell. The benefit of this is that you stick to Python syntax and avoid using MySQL.

```
 $ ipython # enter this at the command-line
 ...
 from myapp.models import MyModel
 M = MyModel.objects.all()
 for m in M:
     m.myfield *= 1.5 # replace with /= 1.5 for division
     m.save()
```